# mysql varchar byte length 255 issue

Tags: mysql

According to the mysql documentation:

> A column uses one length byte if values require no more than 255 bytes,
>   **two length bytes if values may require
>   more than 255 bytes**

AND

> The maximum row size constrains the
>   number of columns because the total
>   width of all columns cannot exceed
>   this size. For example, utf8
>   characters require up to **three bytes
>   per character**, so for a CHAR(255)
>   CHARACTER SET utf8 column, the server
>   must allocate 255 × 3 = 765 bytes per
>   value. Consequently, a table cannot
>   contain more than 65,535 / 765 = 85
>   such columns.

For clarity, what then is the **maximum** value I can set in the varchar argument so it only uses 1 byte to store its length?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [the MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html):

> The CHAR and VARCHAR types are
> declared with a length that indicates
> the maximum number of **characters** you
> want to store. For example, CHAR(30)
> can hold up to 30 characters.
>
> A [VARCHAR] column uses one length
> byte if values require no more than
> 255 **bytes**, two length bytes if
> values may require more than 255
> **bytes**.

This makes the answer to your question depend on the character encoding.

With a single-byte encoding like windows-1252 (which MySQL calls latin1), the character length is the same as the byte length, so you can use a `VARCHAR(255)`.

With UTF-8, a VARCHAR(N) may require up to 3N bytes, as would be the case if all characters were in the range U+0800 to U+FFFF.  Thus, a `VARCHAR(85)` is the greatest that ensures a single-byte byte length (requiring a maximum of 255 bytes).

(Note that MySQL apparently does not support characters outside the BMP.  The official definition of UTF-8 allows 4 bytes per character.)

Comment: For who doesn't know: BMP means "Basic Multilingual Plane". It should be ok for all needs (even covers [CJK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_characters)) unless you need ancient writing characters or fancy symbols.

Comment: What is meant by one length byte? I understand what one byte is, but what is one length byte?

Comment: @vigamage: A "length byte" is a byte used to store the length of a string (separate from the contents of the string).  Having one length byte means the string can be at most 255 bytes long, having two length bytes means the string can be at most 65535 bytes long, etc.

Answer (score 6):

> For clarity, what then is the maximum value I can set in the varchar argument so it only uses 1 byte to store its length?

This depends on the collation of the `VARCHAR` column.

As you noted, `UTF8` *may* use up to three bytes per character, so if your declare a `UTF8` column more than `85` characters long, there is a chance that it will use more than `255` bytes to store its data, and the length hence should be stored in a two-byte field.

If you use `latin1`, each character is stored in `1` byte.

So the answer is:

```
VARCHAR(85) COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI
```

, or

```
VARCHAR(255) COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_CI
```

Comment: It is better to use `COLLATE UTF8_UNICODE_CI` as it is more accurate (unless speed is a #1 issue).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing string size with character representation.

For instance, you could have a character that takes 4 bytes to represent it, and put it inside of string whose max storage size requires only one byte to hold the length since there's less than 255 characters in it.